# unwind and split multiple sub document in Mongo DB using Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Here is an example of the data stored

```
[
   {
      "userId":"user123",
      "name":"John",
      "card":{
         "amount":1000.0,
         "sentMoneyList":[
            {
               "creationDate":"2019-08-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
               "shopId":"merchant1",
               "loyaltyPoint":200,
               "amount":250
            },
            {
               "creationDate":"2019-01-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
               "shopId":"merchant2",
               "loyaltyPoint":100,
               "amount":99
            }
         ],
         "receivedMoneyList":[
            {
               "creationDate":"2019-09-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
               "amount":40
            },
            {
               "creationDate":"2019-03-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
               "amount":500
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

I want to build a timeline of received and sent money of all users starting from a given date.
In case of startDate is `"2019-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000"`, the ouput of my request should be like this:

```
[
   {
      "userId":"user123",
      "name":"John",
      "card":{
         "amount":1000.0,
         "sentMoneyList":[
            {
               "creationDate":"2019-08-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
               "shopId":"merchant1",
               "loyaltyPoint":200,
               "amount":250
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "userId":"user123",
      "name":"John",
      "card":{
         "amount":1000.0,
         "receivedMoneyList":[
            {
               "creationDate":"2019-09-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
               "amount":40
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "userId":"user123",
      "name":"John",
      "card":{
         "amount":1000.0,
         "receivedMoneyList":[
            {
               "creationDate":"2019-03-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
               "amount":500
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Here the java code that tries to get this result:

```
  Criteria criteriaClient = new Criteria();  
  MatchOperation matchOperation = match(criteriaClient.orOperator(
          Criteria.where("card.sentMoneyList.creationDate").gte(startDate),
          Criteria.where("card.receivedMoneyList.creationDate").gte(startDate)));

  UnwindOperation unwindSent = Aggregation.unwind("card.sentMoneyList");
  UnwindOperation unwindReceived = Aggregation.unwind("card.receivedMoneyList");

  Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwindSent, unwindReceived, matchOperation);

   List<UserDTO> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
                aggregation, "users", UserDTO.class).getMappedResults();
```

It gives an empty List. what is missing in the query in order to get the result above ?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried in mongo query? Is that giving you the expected output? I feel, it doesn't

Comment: Let me know, does https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZMYSVhTaK-G this help you, If this is fine, i'll help you to write in spring-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the expected output with `$facet` which helps you to categorize the incoming data. Here I have get **sentMoneyList** array in **sentMoney** array and **receivedMoneyList** array in **receivedMoney**. Then aggregate whatever that gives you the output.

```
public List<Object> test() {
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        facet(
                p -> new Document("$project",
                        new Document("card.receivedMoneyList", 0)
                ),
                a -> new Document("$addFields",
                        new Document("card.sentMoneyList",
                                new Document("$filter",
                                        new Document("input", "$card.sentMoneyList")
                                                .append("cond",
                                                        new Document("$gte", Arrays.asList("$$this.creationDate", "2019-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000"))
                                                )
                                )
                        )
                ),
                unwind("$card.sentMoneyList")

        ).as("sentMoney").and(
                p -> new Document("$project",
                        new Document("card.sentMoneyList", 0)
                ),
                a -> new Document("$addFields",
                        new Document("card.receivedMoney",
                                new Document("$filter",
                                        new Document("input", "$card.receivedMoney")
                                                .append("cond",
                                                        new Document("$gte", Arrays.asList("$$this.creationDate", "2019-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000"))
                                                )
                                )
                        )
                ),
                unwind("$card.receivedMoney")
        ).as("receivedMoney"),
        p -> new Document("$project",
                new Document("combined",
                        new Document("$concatArrays", Arrays.asList("$sentMoney", "$receivedMoney"))
                )
        ),
        unwind("$combined"),
        replaceRoot("combined")

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Users.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

First I request you to use `Object.class` to get the aggregated result and return as a `List<Object>`. If that works fine, then you can convert this model to `UserDTO.class` which should be structured same as output.

You have added a target collection `users` which is not a good practice. So use `mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_TARGET_COLLECTION.class)`

Not : I've not tried this code, but this is written based on working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZMYSVhTaK-G)